# Error while starting react native project

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I am just getting started in react native and followed all the steps given in https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup for `Windows -> Android` .

And I have started the app using `npm start` after that I have tried to run the app in emulator with the command,

`npm run android`

and my package.json looks like,

```
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
```

After entering the above command, I am getting the following error as connection refused,

[image]

Could you please kindly help how can I fix this issue and run the app successfully in the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

1]set environment variable like this

[image]

if you don't know this see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7xdbsjFGtU&t=1579s)

2] cmd for run emulator in you project

```
emulator -avd avd  <---avd is my emulator name
```

3] run your project using this cmd for android

```
react-native run-android
```

**hope this will help you!!**